# PyQt instance variables in constructor

Tags: python, pyqt

In "Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt", the author gives this example in Chapter 4.

It seems to me that `dial`, `spinbox`, and `layout` would go out of scope. Why can we use `dial` instead of `self.dial`, `spinbox` instead of `self.spinbox` and `layout` instead of `self.layout`? Is this a good practice or is it better to use `self.` for all GUI elements?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        dial = QDial()
        dial.setNotchesVisible(True)
        spinbox = QSpinBox()

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(dial)
        layout.addWidget(spinbox)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(dial, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"),
                 spinbox.setValue)
        self.connect(spinbox, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"),
                 dial.setValue)
        self.setWindowTitle("Signals and Slots")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those variables go out of scope.

But since there are references to the underlying objects (via layout and self.setLayout) this is not really an issue, i.e. the widgets/objects are not destroyed.

If you don't need to access them directly in other pieces of your code, then it's just fine like that.

Comment: So in general, if there are **references to underlying objects**, those **underlying objects** will go out of scope when the object referring to them goes out of scope?Is that how this works in Python?

Comment: Yeah, if you delete the layout then the widgets will be removed from memory too.